# Shadow DOM: how to use custom input elements in a native form tag?

Tags: html, angular, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm using Angular8 for creating some custom elements. Some of my custom elements contains an input type.
I need to use shadow DOM, so in my angular component i have setted `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`

Example: myInput.component.html

```
 <slot></slot>
 <input type="text" name="{{myInputTextId}}" id="{{myInputTextId}}">
```

How can i use `<app-myInput></app-myInput>` in a native HTML form? I wan't to have:

```
<form method="POST" action="/saveUsername">
    <app-myInput name="firstName" id="firstId">My text </app-myInput>
</form>
```